# why drop element come on top in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am using jstree which have drag and drop functionality.Actually when ever user drop the element it drop on first position.It should drop on last position.can we drop on last position.I used this js tree
http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=after_close.jstree.
I do the following step

expand the b node and drop the "a" node in "b" node.It now show "a","b-a","b-b".I need to show like this "b-a","b-b","a".
http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/207/

```
$(document).ready(function() {



$('#tree').jstree({
    core: {
       check_callback: function (op, node, node_parent) {

       }
    },
    dnd: {
       check_while_dragging: false
    },
    "plugins": ["dnd"]
 });



});

function isNNode(node) {return node.id.indexOf('not') !== -1;}
```

Thanks

Comment: see this one http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=$.jstree.defaults.dnd&f=$.jstree.defaults.dnd.inside_pos

Comment: it mean I will write last

Comment: can you please give fiddle  so that I will check

Comment: sorry i never use that one i just go through the document.

Comment: Any suggestion of this Question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, update your version of jsTree from 3.0.0 to **jsTree 3.0.2**, then use the following code:

```
$('#tree').jstree({
    core: {
        "check_callback": true
    },
    dnd: {
        "check_while_dragging": false,
        "inside_pos": "last"
    },
    "plugins": ["dnd"]
 });
```

**UPDATE:** I updated your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/210/